# Normal Command Prompt / Console in Visual Studio

Tags: firefox-extensions, visual-studio-2013

Is there any way to add a normal command prompt to Visual Studio?

[image]

I realise the Command Window is the Visual Studio IDE command window. I would like to have the command prompt "CMD" as a window like that.

I want to use JPM (Firefox Addon SDK) installed from NPM just to run and build things. I don't really want to create custom execution scripts etc. It would be nice if the command path would start on the currently selected project but not crucial, as long as I could navigate the command prompt as normal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the Nuget Package Manager Console (Tools -> Package Manager).  This is a Power Shell command prompt, so you can run executables or Power Shell commands from it.

Comment: Sweet! Wow.. I saw Power Shell written there before... but I didn't realise it was a global shell. I thought it was just for NuGet specific context. It works EXACTLY as I wanted. Thank you so much. Hidden in plain sight :)